# How do you verify whether a set of variables uniquely identifies the data in dplyr/tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there a way for dplyr to verify whether a given set of variables uniquely identifies the data within the pipe? This would be useful to verify the data are unique at the level I think they are before merge, etc.

For example, this dataset is uniquely identified by the variables v and z.

```
myData <- tibble(
    v=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
    z=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    y=rnorm(5)
)
```

I am hoping to be able to verify that v and z uniquely identify the data after doing operations with the pip. For example:

```
myData %>%
    mutate(y_squared=y^2) %>%
    verify(any(duplicated(c('v', 'z')))==0)
```

But various iterations of this throw different errors. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use base R's `anyDuplicated` (which returns the number of duplicates, so we compare it to 0).

```
myData %>%
    {anyDuplicated(select(., v, z)) == 0}
# TRUE
```

It will return `TRUE` if there are no duplicates within those columns, and `FALSE` if there are duplicates.

Comment: Oh cool. Sorry for the basic questions, but:

1) What do the brackets {} around the expression do?
2) If I edited myData in the pipe above the anyDuplicated command, would the "." that passes the data to anyDuplicated be the updated data or just the original one?

Comment: The curly braces are there for order of operations. `==` has a higher precedence than `%>%`, so without the braces R will unfortunately try to compare `anyDuplicated(...) == 0` *before* piping the data in! The `{}` groups what's inside as a single expression, so R knows to pipe into the whole thing.

Comment: The `.` refers to whatever data you pipe in, which should be whatever data you want to check. The example in my question shows how to check a data frame, but the result will be TRUE of FALSE. If you want to check something in the middle of a pipeline, continuing on if everything is expected, but stopping if there is a problem, we could write a wrapper... is that what you want?

Comment: Wow thanks so much for your help Gregor this is really helpful. New to R as of this week. 

I think I got it working with:

```
myData %>%
    mutate... %>%
    filter... %>%
    verify(anyDuplicated(select(.,v,z))==0)
```

So it looks like it is working even without the {}. Do you know why that might be? It slow seems to read the already edited (mutated and filtered) data into the operation, which is what I wanted. But trying to make sure I understand the syntax.

Comment: In your comments, `verify()` is containing the `anyDuplicated(...) == 0`, so the `verify()` is playing the same role as the `{}` in my answer.

Comment: Yes, what I did as at the end of the pipe I put a "-> newData" to output the actions of the whole thing to a new file. Thanks again Gregor

Comment: Deleting my previous comment - the `verify()` takes care of that. Hadn't used it before, it's a nice function!

Answer (score 0):

Here  is one possibility using `add_count`:

```
myData %>%
  add_count(v, z) %>%
  filter(n != 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am hoping to do this in a way that doesn't actually edit the data, though (per the filter command you have). Do you know if there is anyway to simply verify that those variables uniquely identify the data?

Answer (score 0):

This shows the duplicate rows:

```
myData %>%
    mutate(y_squared=y^2) %>%
    filter(duplicated(.[ ,c("v", "z")]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am hoping to do this in a way that doesn't actually edit the data, though (per the filter command you have). Do you know if there is anyway to simply verify that those variables uniquely identify the data?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can check in base R:

```r
length(unique(paste(myData$v, myData$z))) == nrow(myData)
```

If you want to use a piped statement:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myData <- tibble(
    v=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
    z=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    y=rnorm(5) )

myData %>% summarize(is_v_z_unique = length(unique(paste(.$v, .$z))) == nrow(myData))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   is_v_z_unique
#>   <lgl>        
#> 1 TRUE
```

And here is what it looks like if you only want 1 (for TRUE) and 0 (for FALSE):

```r
library(tidyverse)

myData <- tibble(
    v=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
    z=c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    y=rnorm(5) )

myData %>% summarize(is_v_z_unique = length(unique(paste(.$v, .$z))) == nrow(myData)) %>% 
    unlist() %>% as.numeric() 
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Got it, but no way to do this within the pipe? I am hoping to be able to do actions above and then conclude the pipe by verifying the uniqueness of the data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to do this in the dplyr workflow then the ouput needs to somehow fit into your workflow. How do you envision to report if myData$v and myData$z uniquely identify your data?

Comment: I was just hoping it to output a 1/0 where it is True if the data are unique at that level. The summarize via the pipe makes sense, but I am trying to do this in a way where it doesn't actually edit the data (the summarize command is collapsing it down to 1 row). i.e. I just want to verify in the pipe that the code is unique at the v-z level and have the code error out if it is not. Does that make sense?

Comment: Since the current command is not reassigning any values, it is not actually altering any of  the data. And I added code so it spits out 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

Comment: Sorry I think I am being unclear. I am hoping to do this in a pipe where I am making other alterations to the data and then check at the end that the data are unique. I see how your code verifies uniqueness, but the output of that pipe is just a 1/0. This means to do the check I would need to do it in its own pipe rather than in my existing pipe where I am making other edits to the data, right?

Comment: No. You can replace the initial `myData %>%` with any other output from whatever you like. However, pipes only transform data--they can not bifurcate (as far as I know). So they final transformation step of the whole transformation is you end up either with a 1 or a 0.